# Check If Xamarin Android App is connected to one of two networks

Tags: c#, networking, xamarin, network-programming, detection

I am writing a Xamarin Android app, I want to be able to know via an event when a user hops from network(net 1) to another network(net 2)and process some logic after wards. I came across this plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin but the problem is, the plugin may trigger events on network interfaces I do not monitor like 3G and I don't want this. I'll like to know how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a connectivity change of the wireless SSID or ...?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. i.e a network change that makes the app acquire a new IP

Comment: Now you are saying IP address... what if a new/different Wifi SSID connection returns the same IP address, or the same IP subnet, or... What exactly are you trying to track?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with networking. What I want to achieve in my app is to be able to detect via an event trigger whenever my app is connected to either wifi network 1 or wifi network 2. How should I go about detecting of the when my android app is connected to either of the networks only

Answer (score 1):

You can track network changes via an Android `BroadcastReceiver`, here is a quick example that tracks changes to wifi SSIS that you can customize to meet your needs.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { WifiManager.NetworkStateChangedAction, WifiManager.WifiStateChangedAction })]
public class NetworkBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    readonly WifiManager wifiManager;
    public static string LastSSID;

    public NetworkBroadcastReceiver(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    }

    public NetworkBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string currentSSID = null;
        if (WifiManager.NetworkStateChangedAction == intent.Action)
        {
            var netInfo = (NetworkInfo)intent.GetParcelableExtra(WifiManager.ExtraNetworkInfo);
            var netInfoDetailed = netInfo.GetDetailedState();
            if (netInfo.IsConnected || netInfoDetailed == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.Connected) 
            {
                currentSSID = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SSID;
            }
            else if (!netInfo.IsConnected)
            {
                currentSSID = null;
            }
        }
        if (WifiManager.WifiStateChangedAction == intent.Action)
        {
            currentSSID = GetCurrentSSID();
        }
        if (LastSSID != currentSSID)
        {
            // Do something on SSID change....
            Toast.MakeText(context, $"Wireless SSID changed, from:{LastSSID} to:{currentSSID}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            LastSSID = currentSSID;
        }
    }

    public static string GetCurrentSSID()
    {
        var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        if (wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SupplicantState == SupplicantState.Completed)
        {
            return wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SSID;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: make sure you have add permissions to your manifest (`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`)

If needed, you can set initial tracking SSID in your app startup by calling:

```
NetworkBroadcastReceiver.LastSSID = NetworkBroadcastReceiver.GetCurrentSSID();
```

Or just retrieve the current SSID via:

```
var ssid = NetworkBroadcastReceiver.GetCurrentSSID();
```